# What is the difference between default access token and json web token

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I am building a website and I am using asp.net web api 2 with **Identity** framework and **Oauth** for Authorization .
I would like to know the differences between default web token and json web token (JWT) and in which cases we use each one?

Comment: Where are you seeing the term default web token?

Comment: Default web token it's a random token generated by authorization server unlike JWT that contains information about the authorized user.

Answer (score 0):

> JSON Web Token (JWT) [JWT] is a JSON-based [RFC7159] security token
>   encoding that enables identity and security information to be shared
>   across security domains.  A security token is generally issued by an
>   Identity Provider and consumed by a Relying Party that relies on its
>   content to identify the token's subject for security-related
>   purposes.
>
> The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework [RFC6749] provides a method for 
>   making authenticated HTTP requests to a resource using an access
>   token.  Access tokens are issued to third-party clients by an
>   authorization server (AS) with the (sometimes implicit) approval of
>   the resource owner.  In OAuth, an authorization grant is an abstract
>   term used to describe intermediate credentials that represent the
>   resource owner authorization.  An authorization grant is used by the
>   client to obtain an access token.  Several authorization grant types
>   are defined to support a wide range of client types and user
>   experiences.  OAuth also allows for the definition of new extension
>   grant types to support additional clients or to provide a bridge
>   between OAuth and other trust frameworks.  Finally, OAuth allows the
>   definition of additional authentication mechanisms to be used by
>   clients when interacting with the authorization server.

About default web access  , i think it is only a general token.